# Using ObjectContext / DbContext inside T4 Text Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, t4

I've been searching for an example on how to use Entity Framework (ObjectContext/DbContext) inside of T4 template. How can I achieve this? Currently in my T4 I need to get values from database tables to generate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T4 template is just C# or VB.NET code inside some markup so you will use it in the exactly same way as you do that in any other code file.

Comment: It say that it cannot locate my assembly that contains the EDMX file. How do I overcome this?

Comment: By referencing the assembly with EDMX file? ObjectContext with EDMX file includes multiple resources into its assembly. If you want to use it you must either define the context in separate assembly and use it from your template or you must get those resources and use them directly.

Comment: Let me clear things up.
I'm trying to create data annotations for entities in an EDMX file.
I'm trying to generate these data annotations using T4.
The data annotations will be generated from validation table in the database.
I need to access the validation table using Entity Framework rather than using SqlReader.